# Is there a schema search tool for postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a schema search tool similar to Redgate [SQL search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) available for postgres (preferably free or part of jetbrains suite)?  I need the ability to do things such as scan a database(s) for the existence of a column in some unknown table X.

System Info:

postgresql v9.5
[DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)
Mac

Comment: `select distinct table_schema, table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'some_column'`